# Variable declared with let or const do not become direct property of `window` object in chrome console, why?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In the chrome console, when I declare variables with `let` or `const` these DO NOT become the property of `window` object. However, the variable declared with `var` DO becomes the direct property of the window object in the chrome console. For e.g:

```
let sayHi = 'Hi'
const greet = 'Good Morning'
var sayHola = 'Hola Hola'

window.hasOwnProperty('sayHi') //false
window.hasOwnProperty('greet') //false
window.hasOwnProperty('sayHola') //true
```

Then what are the actual scopes/object of a variable declared with `let` or `const` in the chrome console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All variables (whether declared with `var`, `const`, or `let`) declared in the console are global by default, but being a property of the `window` object is not the same as having global scope.

This actually isn't just something that happens in the console, variables defined with `let` and `const` never are set as properties to `window`. See this snippet:

```js
let sayHi = 'Hi';
const greet = 'Good Morning';
var sayHola = 'Hola Hola';

console.log(window.hasOwnProperty('sayHi')); // => false
console.log(window.hasOwnProperty('greet')); // => false
console.log(window.hasOwnProperty('sayHola')); // => true
```

This behavior is intentional and is set out by the standard. It allows for better isolation of variables to specific scopes and no meddling from outside that scope.

Comment: I am more interested in knowing what are the actual scopes/object of a variable declared with let or const in the chrome console?

Comment: @dkjain Variables declared in the console have a global scope by default unless you define them inside of a block. I've updated my answer to reflect that.